# The Nehalel Siddur and the Rema in OC 90:23

Tags: halacha, prayer-book

[The Nehalel Siddur](http://www.nehalel.com/index.html) is a Siddur which pictures accompanying prayer text. (Some examples of the pages in the Siddur can be seen [here](http://www.nehalel.com/seenehalelbechol.html#SeeNBC) and [here](http://www.nehalel.com/see_beShabbat.html)).

The Rema in [Orach Chayim 90:23](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.90.23?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says the following:

(*Source provided by [Sefaria.org](https://www.sefaria.org/)*)

(*Partial Quote*)

> וְלָכֵן אָסוּר גַּם כֵּן לָצוּר צִיּוּרִים בַּסְּפָרִים שֶׁמִּתְפַּלְּלִים מֵהֶם, שֶׁלֹּא תִּתְבַּטֵּל הַכַּוָּנָה (מָרְדְּכַי 
>     רֵישׁ פֶּרֶק כָּל הַצְלָמִים)
>
> *Therefore it is also forbidden to make images in books that (individuals) pray from, so as not to ruin their focus (in prayer)*

Is the production/use of such Siddurim permitted Halachically? If they are, why are they?

Comment: Wow, great question! i use this siddur a lot. I was also wondering about its permissibility, because it has some pictures of people and heavenly bodies which I'm not sure are allowed (especially while praying)

Comment: Doesn't the intro to the Siddur address this?

Comment: It certainly seems to be a beautiful siddur, from the sample pages on the website. Haggadot were frequently illustrated in the Middle Ages, but I think siddurim to a lesser extent. However,  http://blogs.bl.uk/digitisedmanuscripts/2012/02/hebrew-illuminated-manuscripts-online.html and http://www.e-codices.unifr.ch/en/bc/b-0028/23r  seem to indicate that there were examples of siddurim with a few pictures, so maybe not everyone holds by the Rema.

Comment: note that what qualifies as tefillah in the remah's statement will very likely not include all of davening. I'd be interested in seeing their shmonah esreah, for example

Comment: @Orangesandlemons there are images there also at least based on the sample pictures.

Comment: @Epicentre I just looked at the Dirshu Mishna Brura and there doesn't seem to be any Kulas with this idea.

Comment: I think that the Mordechai is plausibly only about manuscript illumination, and not pictures that **underscore** the meaning of the words. In practice, some people find Nehalalel helpful for their kavanah, others -- a distraction. Our family "argues" over the benchers, some preferring them, some asking to be passed another.

Comment: @michaberger the Rema/Mordecai passage doesn't seem to have any qualifiers that would support your contention. Perhaps the Nehallel siddur would be of more use as preparation for prayer, not during prayer itself. IMHO this would apply to translated works as well, but I digress.

Comment: As the quote says "שֶׁלֹּא תִּתְבַּטֵּל הַכַּוָּנָה". Which would seem to exclude pictures that (for you) promote kavanah. This is the same se'if that discusses distracting clothing, illustrations on the shul walls (at eye level) and on which the Be'er Heiteiv prohibits praying in front of a mirror. The topic appears to be pictures that distract, and not considering pictures used to focus. (Your reasoning would imply the mechaber would ban Shevivis.)

Comment: I think your reading of the Rema is more of a stretch than mine. I don't see the Rema making any distinctions at all; I will have to see the Mordechai inside, however. If you have a source that supports your position, I'll go with it.